# Comparing two rows in Oracle DB and Showing Column Mismatch

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Table Columns: Id, Name, Age

First Rows:

```
select 11, 'James', 22 from dual;
```

This will return

```
11 James 22
```

Second Row:

```
select * from supplier where id=11`;
```

This will return

```
11 Vinod 25
```

Now I wanted to compare both rows:

```
11 James 22
11 Vinod 25
```

It should return the columns which has differences.

> Name Mismatch
>     Age Mismatch

I am using 12c is there Built in feature in oracle which will solve this.
Or any other ways from which I can achieve the solution for the same.

Thanks In advance..

`

Comment: are all the rows you want to compare present in the same table?

Comment: I am comparing my static data row with table data row

Comment: There's no such built in functionality. But it seems pretty simple to achieve. What are the blockers?

Comment: I am quite new to oracle stuff.. so Not able to achieve this :(

Comment: What is 11?  Will there always only be two rows?

Comment: 11 is Id(Primary Key) and yes there is two rows comparison only..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj29840.html) and [`decode`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) (can use [`case`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) alternatively) to find out if  column value matches:

```
with cte(id, name, age) as (select 11, 'James', 22 from dual)
select 
  s.id,
  decode(s.name, t.name, null, 'Name mismatch') name_check,
  decode(s.age, t.age, null, 'Age mismatch') age_check
from supplier s
inner join cte t
on s.id = t.id
where s.id = 11;
```